# Why is rate limit similar with authorized and anonymous access to GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

When I send request with Postman and check response header I can see this:

[image]

When I try with old PAT I created, or with OAuth token after validation (I created app and validated user with OAuth flow from my DB, so I used this token in Postman just to check) to call GitHub REST API like this: `https://api.github.com/repos/djordjeviclazar/rep/branches`
and set `access_token` in header like in [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/basics-of-authentication), I can see in headers `X-RateLimit-Limit` is 60, and I could see that `X-RateLimit-Remaining` is less than 60.

From [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api):

> For API requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up to 5,000 requests per hour.

> Authenticated requests are associated with the authenticated user, regardless of whether Basic Authentication or an OAuth token was used. This means that all OAuth applications authorized by a user share the same quota of 5,000 requests per hour when they authenticate with different tokens owned by the same user.

So I guess that means I can't make more tokens and expect more than 5000 requests per hour, but why only 60, why API treats my requests as anonymous? Also I think that Search API is more limiting. What is the right way to access GitHub REST API?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Github if you face any problem with their API?

Comment: @NicoHaase No I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that this call is not authenticated since you've specified:

- Add To `Headers`
- Key: `access_token`
- Value: `{{PAT}}`

It will add an HTTP header with the following value: `access_token: [PAT value]` which is not processed by Github.

Checkout the headers sent in the headers tab it should print `Authorization: Token YOUR_TOKEN` or `Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN`

The following configuration will work correctly:

[image]

- Add To `Headers`
- Key: `Authorization`
- Value: `Token {{PAT}}` (also `Bearer {{PAT}}` works)

You can also use Authorization of Type `Bearer Token` which is the same as `Bearer XXXX`:

[image]

Also, you can also disable Authorization (to the value `No`), and in the headers, just append the `Authorization` header:

[image]

Note that the usage of `access_token` in the url query parameters has been [deprecated since end 2019](https://developer.github.com/changes/2019-11-05-deprecated-passwords-and-authorizations-api/#authenticating-using-query-parameters)

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried this now, but in both cases `Token {{PAT}}` and `{{PAT}}` returns same header: `X-RateLimit-Limit: 60`. However I agree with part when you say that GitHub ignores my token because when I look in header it counts every request even when I send anonymous (but it could possibly be that GitHub only looks IP address).

Comment: @LazarĐorđević checkout the headers sent in the headers tab it should print `Authorization: Token YOUR_TOKEN` or `Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN`

Comment: @LazarĐorđević also the key must be changed to `Authorization` if you are using `Add To Headers` and authorization Type `API key`

Comment: You were right. Interesting. I will accept this answer, please edit your answer with this information from comment. I tried also different token (PAT is not working for me, but in my case I tried both tokens, so previous way is not working for sure)